# 27 spaces, 27 curious places

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, geometry, no-computers

**Grid 1:**

[image: Grid 1]

**Grid 2:**

[image: Grid 2]

**Grid 3:**

[image: Grid 3]

---

Find the meaning behind these images.

Hint 1:

> The puzzle involves three-dimensional Euclidean space.

Hint 2:

> Cube.

Hint 3:

> Coordinates.

Comment: I have an idea, but it's related to something that definitely requires the knowledge-tag in order to solve it but since you added the knowledge-tag later, I'm not so sure...

Comment: @Prim3numbah It's worth a shot; the knowledge tag is there, isn't it?

Comment: @BlueHerring Yes, but since it says "may be relevant" in the description of the edit I'm not that sure. I might post a rot13 comment later, to see if I'm on the right track or completely off.

Comment: @Prim3numbah - I'm not sure if the puzzle needs "knowledge" tag myself. It doesn't provide everything needed to solve it itself, so some outside knowledge is required.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with rot13(fgnef/pbafgryyngvbaf) or is this completely off?

Comment: @Prim3numbah - rot13(fgnef/pbafgryyngvbaf) do not have anything to do with the puzzle. Tags should provide hints as to what does.

Comment: Yes, suspected that but felt I just had to ask. I can leave that idea now.

Comment: @webadventurer any more hints?

Comment: @SnySmartie - added another hint

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

> Each of the rows on each grid represent a set of 3D coordinates except for the bottom row of the third grid. The empty squares represent zeros and the squares with a horizontal line represents 1. From left to right it is the (x,y,z) coordinates respectively. The result is that in three-dimensional Euclidean space the 8 set of coordinates map out the vertices of a cube like so:

> [image]

The significance of 27

> Is the fact that it is a perfect cube number!

Comment: This answer is correct, but there is a remarkable detail here. If one were to draw a cube in three-dimensional Euclidean space with the side length of 2 and centered on 0, then all its vertices would be on either +/- 1 x/y/z. Cells with no strokes would contain +1, cells with strokes would contain -1.

Comment: Sorry did I miss something that I should add in my answer??

Comment: No, your answer is not wrong, I accept it. I was just expecting a different answer. Now I see yours is also valid. In a nutshell, if you put 1s in all cells except those with diagonal strokes, they will be coordinates of a cube centered on 0 with side length of 2. Cells with horizontal strokes will have -1s.